# Html2Canvas is not able to render multiple DIVs properly when The number of DIVs increases significantly

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html2canvas

I want to render multiple rows from table(HTML). Render one row as one image (In attached image mentioned labels like image1, image2...). Table is generating on run time.

I have tried following code but didn't work.

```
html2canvas($('.row.indicator-table-header'), { // render table header image
onrendered: function(canvas) {
    indicatorTable=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var indi=0;
    indicatorTableBodyImage();
    console.log('Start0 : '+indi);  

    function indicatorTableBodyImage() {
        indi++; 
        console.log('Start1 : '+indi);  
        if(indi == indicatorTableBodyLength) {
            console.log('Start3 : '+indi);

            form_submit('test_image_report', {
                indicatorTableBodyArray : indicatorTableBodyArray
            }, 
            'post');
        }
        console.log('Start4 : '+indi);  

html2canvas($('.row.indicator-table-body'), {  // render table body image
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        console.log('Start5 : '+indi);
            indicator_table_body=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            indicatorTableBodyArray[indi] = indicator_table_body;
            indicatorTableBodyImage();
            console.log('Start6 : '+indi);


    }});
console.log('Start7End : '+indi);
    } // close of for loop
```

}});

HTML page as follows : 
[HTML Table which i want to render as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pomiN.png)

[html2canvas not working for multiple div as canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22633795/html2canvas-not-working-for-multiple-div-as-canvas?rq=1)